# apache reverse proxy with django authentication and geoserver

Tags: django, reverse-proxy, django-authentication, geoserver

i want to use django authentication before redirectiong to geoserver using apache reverse-proxy, i can Redirect to login page but after submitting the /login/?next=/geoserver return me to first page not to geoserver

i tried a lot of configuratin but now success:

```
<VirtualHost *:9443>
ServerName localhost
ProxyPreserveHost On

# Proxy requests for GeoServer to Django
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /geoserver /

 # Redirect /geoserver requests to Django authentication
<Location /geoserver>
    Redirect /geoserver /login/?next=/geoserver
</Location>

# Proxy all other requests to Django
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```

Comment: What did you set as the proxy URL on the global settings page?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/geoserver